# SSDT How to: Deploy .dacpac without losing custom client database objects?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, deployment, version-control, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using the Database project in Visual Studio.

In my scenario I have customers who intuitively customize the database I provide for them.

For example, the client contracts a third party to create a customized system for them, then this third creates some tables in my database.

I know I should never allow third party access to my database but the company I'm working they allow this.

How can I make when deploying .dacpac these objects that are not part of my schema are not excluded? I think this probably is not possible, what can I do in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible, and often very useful. There are probably objects in your target that you do not want to drop. We Always drop our objects in our production dbs in a controlled fashion (not automatically), using a separate drop-script.

There is an msbuild parameter not to drop objects found in target but not in source.
Just use parameter "Drop objects in target but not in Project" to false. This setting will leave those objects untouched. The option is also there when publishing from within VS.

DropObjectsNotInSource=FALSE

Comment: please, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150625/ssdt-how-to-deploy-dacpac-ignoring-drop-columns-on-target

Answer (score 4):

you are in luck as I have just released a deployment filter that will do exactly what you want!

https://github.com/GoEddie/DeploymentContributorFilterer

What this will do is let you ignore or if you want to deploy updates, just not drop objects if they exist.

If you are using sqlpackage.exe to deploy your dacpac's add these command line:

```
/p:AdditionalDeploymentContributors=AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor
/p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="SqlPackageFilter=IgnoreName(.*RegexThatMatchesYourObjectsOrUseASchemaMatchAndPutThemInTheirOwnSchema.*)"
```

If you are using the publish option in SSDT (inside visual studio) then add them to the publish profile.xml

Technically what this does, is when you run a deployment, the filter gets called for every operation (create, drop, alter) and if we match the regex we simply remove it from the script so that the drop in this case is never actually executed.

Comment: Thank you Ed Elliott! 

Your solution also works, but in my scenario SAS solution is embedded in a simpler way. Thanks for replying!

Comment: oh vicious! ha ha, glad you have it working and welcome to moder sql development with ssdt!

Comment: Interesting Ed, I will try to take a look when I find sime time. Thank's for sharing!

Comment: Really a great tool, @EdElliott! I'll give it a try ASAP. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: please, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150625/ssdt-how-to-deploy-dacpac-ignoring-drop-columns-on-target

Comment: Ed, thank you for the dll. I’m in the similar situation where in I’m getting “Dropping unnamed constraint on table” which is not ignored even with the filter IgnoreSchema!(mySchema).
Any hint would be much appreciated.