# SSDT How to: Deploy .dacpac ignoring drop columns on target

Tags: database, visual-studio, deployment, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using the Database project in Visual Studio.

In my scenario I have customers who intuitively customize the database I provide for them, e.g. adding some columns in existing tables, adding new tables...

How can I make when deploying .dacpac these objects that are not part of my schema are not excluded?

Important:

**Set DropObjectsNotInSource=FALSE is not working for table columns.**

**EDIT**

Ed, please see if I am doing something wrong:

```
using (DacPackage dacPackage = DacPackage.Load(DacPacFileName))
{
     var dacServices = new DacServices(ConnectionString);

     var dacOptions = new DacDeployOptions
     {
         AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments = "SqlPackageFilter=KeepTableColumns(*)"
     };

     dacServices.Deploy(dacPackage, NomeBancoDados, true, dacOptions);
}
```

Is '*' in table filter "ALL TABLES" ?

I tried a table name too, but it did not work.

Comment: If they're adding columns to tables you created, I don't know that you can do much about that out of the box. You can definitely ignore objects they create, but it might be worth having a conversation with your customers about not modifying "your" tables and only creating/maintaining their own. If they need new columns added to existing tables, that should be part of your development. They could easily add something that could break your code if they're not careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this for this scenario:

https://agilesqlclub.codeplex.com

You can "Keep" which deploys objects if they do not exist but does not deploy if there are changes or "Ignore" to completely ignore.

You can do this on type or name (regex)

Ed

Comment: Tks Ed, how can i use SqlPackageFilter=KeepTableColumns(Employees) for all tables, e.g: SqlPackageFilter=KeepTableColumns(ALL or *)  ?

Comment: I'am using nuget DacFramework, where should i put the AgileSqlClub.SqlPackageFilter.dll to deploy?

Comment: I'm trying to use the tool by following the documentation but so far no success :/

Comment: please, review my question o/